# How to import Birthday list from facebook?

Tags: android

i want to import friend list of user to my app, along with their birthday from facebook. Besides it must work for every user whoever uses this app. how can i perform it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far and the part you have problem with. Read [help tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask good questions.

Comment: i am sorry for unclarification. Actually my app sends birthday sms to every user running in background. and now i want the contacts to be added from facebook. and i dont know where to begin. i tried by using token but i didnt got it...:)

Answer (score 0):

Please use Facebook Graph API, its very easy to get friends information please have a look this.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user